# Urban Airship : Push Notification with Phonegap not working

Tags: ios, cordova

Can you please tell me what i am missing

I am using phone gap to develop hybrid APP.

My `config.xml` looks like

```
<preference name=“com.urbanairship.developmentappkey” value=“*******RhKiHsW9pASskA ” />
<preference name=“com.urbanairship.developmentappsecret” value=“****2QDjOZJM1g ” />
<preference name=“com.urbanairship.inproduction” value=“No” />
```

when i build app using XCODE then in console following info is been logged

```
1.278017ms
2014-06-26 20:09:57.793 Mercer Select[745:60b] [W] -[UAConfig validate] [Line 152] Development App Key is not valid.
2014-06-26 20:09:57.794 Mercer Select[745:60b] [W] -[UAConfig validate] [Line 156] Development App Secret is not valid.
2014-06-26 20:09:57.795 Mercer Select[745:60b] [W] -[UAConfig validate] [Line 160] Production App Key is not valid.
2014-06-26 20:09:57.796 Mercer Select[745:60b] [W] -[UAConfig validate] [Line 164] Production App Secret is not valid.
2014-06-26 20:09:57.797 Mercer Select[745:60b] [E] -[UAConfig validate] [Line 168] Current App Key (***RhKiHsW9pASskA ) is not valid.
2014-06-26 20:09:57.798 Mercer Select[745:60b] [E] -[UAConfig validate] [Line 173] Current App Secret (****2Q_DjOZJM1g ) is not valid.
2014-06-26 20:09:57.799 Mercer Select[745:60b] [E] +[UAirship executeUnsafeTakeOff:] [Line 141] The AirshipConfig.plist file is missing and no application credentials were specified at runtime.
```

My JS Code look like : I am writing below code inside device.ready event

```
       document.addEventListener("urbanairship.registration", function (event) {
            alert("Inside");
            if (event.error) {
                alert('there was an error registering for push notifications');
            } else {
                alert("Registered with ID: " + event.pushID);
            }
        }, false);

        document.addEventListener("urbanairship.push", function (event) {
            alert("Incoming push: " + event.message);
        }, false);
```

Comment: No event is been recorded. nither of the alert runs :-(

Comment: Read the docs: https://github.com/urbanairship/phonegap-ua-push#ios-manual-installation-unnecessary-if-installed-automatically